# Indent message in Boost Log V2

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

Boost.Log 1.75.0:

We use product-wise such messages: `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) <<  "\tMessage";` to indent the log and highlight the the next n line belongs together (note the "\t" at the beginning).

Is there any "official" to do such an indention? I read about scoped logging, but as I see it, it is only to add line at the beginning and at the end.

The expected outcome would be like this:

> [info] - Parent message
>
> [info] - ____ indented child message

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in tool for this kind of formatting, but you could implement it in your custom formatter. For example, you could do it this way:

```
thread_local unsigned int g_indent = 0u;

std::string indent_formatter()
{
    return std::string(g_indent, '_');
}

sink->set_formatter(boost::log::expressions::stream
    << boost::phoenix::bind(&indent_formatter) << " " << boost::log::expressions::smessage);
```

Here, you need to use `boost::phoenix::bind` to make `indent_formatter` a [Boost.Phoenix](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/index.html) expression so that it is compatible with the formatting expression it is part of. There are other ways of writing your custom formatter, including writing it as a [single function](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/formatters.html#log.tutorial.formatters.custom_formatting_functions).

Now, when you need to change the indentation level, you only need to update `g_indent`. It is useful to write a scope guard class to automate this:

```
class auto_indent_level
{
public:
    auto_indent_level() noexcept { ++g_indent; }
    ~auto_indent_level() { --g_indent; }

    auto_indent_level(auto_indent_level const&) = delete;
    auto_indent_level& operator= (auto_indent_level const&) = delete;
};

void bar()
{
    auto_indent_level ail;
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "bar()"; // indented one level
}

void foo()
{
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "foo()"; // not indented
    bar();
}
```

Note that this will not work with [asynchronous](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_frontends.html#log.detailed.sink_frontends.async) logging, since in that case log record formatting happens in a different thread. If you need this to work with asynchronous logging then you need to attach `g_indent` to the logging record (for example, using the [`add_value`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/utilities.html#log.detailed.utilities.manipulators.add_value) manipulator) and then extract it from the record in the formatter.